# Why doesn't SSIS recognize line feed {LF} row delimiter while importing UTF-8 flat file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, utf-8, ssis, flat-file

I am trying to import data from a utf-8 encoded flat file into SQL Server 2008 using SSIS. This is what the end of the row data looks like in Notepad++:

[image]

I have a couple more images showing what the file connection manager looks like:

[image]

[image]

You can see that the data shows correctly in the file connection manager preview. When I try to import this data, no rows import. I get an error message indicating that the row delimiter was not found. You can see in the file connection manager images that the header row delimiter and the row delimiter are both set to `{LF}`. This was sufficient to generate the correct preview, so I am lost to why it did not work to import. I have tried a number of things that have brought zero results:

- Tried using the Wizard import in SSMS...same results
- Tried using data conversion, no impact
- Tried setting the row delimiter to (0a), same results

> [Flat File Source [582]] Warning: The
>   end of the data file was reached while
>   reading header rows. Make sure the
>   header row delimiter and the number of
>   header rows to skip are correct.

Thanks for looking at this and I really appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### Cause:

SSIS fails to read the file and displays the below warning due to the column delimiter **`Ç`** (*"c" with cedilla*) and **`not`** due to the line delimiter **`{LF}`** (*Line Feed*).

```
[Read flat file [1]] Warning: The end of the data file was reached while 
reading header rows. Make sure the header row delimiter and the number of 
header rows to skip are correct.
```

Here is a sample SSIS package that shows how to resolve the issue using `Script Component` and at the end there is another example that simulates your issue.

### Resolution:

Below sample package is written in `SSIS 2008 R2`. It reads a flat file with row delimiter **`{LF}`** as a single column value; then splits the data using `Script Component` to insert the information into a table in `SQL Server 2008 R2` database.

Use [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to create a simple flat file with few rows. The below sample file has *Product Id* and *List Price* information on each row separated by **`Ç`** as column delimiter and each row ends with **`{LF}`** delimiter.

[image: Flat file source]

On the Notepad++, click *`Encoding`* and then click *`Encoding in UTF-8`* to save the flat file in **`UTF-8`** encoding.

[image: Encoding UTF-8]

The sample will use an `SQL Server 2008 R2` database named **`Sora`**. Create a new table named `dbo.ProductListPrice` using the below given script. SSIS will insert the flat file data into this table.

```
USE Sora;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ProductListPrice
(
        ProductId   nvarchar(30)    NOT NULL
    ,   ListPrice   numeric(12,2)   NOT NULL
);
GO
```

Create an SSIS package using *Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) 2008 R2*. Name the package as *`SO_6268205.dtsx`*. Create a data source named *`Sora.ds`* to connect to the database `Sora` in *SQL Server 2008 R2*.

Right-click anywhere inside the package and then click *`Variables`* to view the variables pane. Create a new variable named *`ColumnDelimiter`* of data type *`String`* in the package scope *`SO_6268205`* and set the variable with the value **`Ç`**

[image: Package variables]

Right-click on the *`Connection Managers`* and click *`New Flat File Connection...`* to create a connection to read the flat file.

[image: Flat File Connection]

On the *`General`* page of the *Flat File Connection Manager Editor*, perform the following actions:

- Set *Connection manager name* to *`ProductListPrice`*
- Set *Description* to *`Flat file connection manager to read product list price information.`*
- Select the flat file path. I have the file in the path *`C:\Siva\StackOverflow\Files\6268205\ProductListPrice.txt`*
- Select **`{LF}`** from *Header Row Delimiter*
- Check *`Column names in the first data row`*
- Click *`Columns`* page

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor - General]

On the *`Columns`* page of the *Flat File Connection Manager Editor*, verify that the *`Column delimiter`* is blank and disabled. Click *`Advanced`* page.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor - Columns]

On the *`Advanced`* page of the *Flat File Connection Manager Editor*, perform the following actions.

- Set the *Name* to *`LineData`*
- Verify that the *Column delimiter* is set to *`{LF}`*
- Set the *DataType* to *`Unicode string [DT_WSTR]`*
- Set the *OutputColumnWidth* to *`255`*
- Click the *`Preview`* page.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor - Advanced]

On the *`Preview`* page of the *Flat File Connection Manager Editor*, verify that the displayed data looks correct and click **`OK`**.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor - Preview]

You will see the data source *Sora* and the flat file connection manager *ProductListPrice* on the *`Connection Managers`* tab at the bottom of the package.

[image: Connection Managers]

Drag and drop `Data Flow Task` onto the *Control Flow* tab of the package and name it as *`File to database - Without Cedilla delimiter`*

[image: Data Flow Task 1]

Double-click the *Data Flow Task* to switch the view to the *`Data Flow`* tab on the package. Drag and drop a *`Flat File Source`* on the *Data Flow* tab. Double-click the *Flat File Source* to open *`Flat File Source Editor`*.

On the *`Connection Manager`* page of the *Flat File Source Editor*, select the *Flat File Connection Manager* `ProductListPrice` and click *Columns* page.

[image: Flat File Source Editor - Connection Manager]

On the *`Columns`* page of the *Flat File Source Editor*, check the column *`LineData`* and click *`OK`*.

[image: Flat File Source Editor - Columns]

Drag and drop a *`Script Component`* onto the *Data Flow* tab below the *Flat File Source*, select *`Transformation`* and click *`OK`*. Connect the green arrow from *Flat File Source* to *Script Component*. Double-click *Script Component* to open *`Script Transformation Editor`*.

Click *Input Columns* on *Script Transformation Editor* and select *`LineData`* column. Click *Inputs and Outputs* page.

[image: Script Transformation Editor - Input Columns]

On the *`Inputs and Outputs`* page of the *Script Transformation Editor*, perform the following actions.

- Change the inputs name to FlatFileInput
- Change the outputs name to *`SplitDataOutput`*
- Select *Output Columns* and click *`Add Column`*. Repeat this again to add another column.
- Name the first column *`ProductId`*
- Set the *DataType* of column *ProductId* to *`Unicode string [DT_WSTR]`*
- Set the *Length* to *`30`*

[image: Script Transformation Editor - Inputs and Outputs - ProductId]

On the *`Inputs and Outputs`* page of the *Script Transformation Editor*, perform the following actions.

- Name the second column *`ListPrice`*
- Set the *DataType* of column *ListPrice* to *`numeric [DT_NUMERIC]`*
- Set the *Precision* to *`12`*
- Set the *Scale* to *`2`*
- Click *Script* page to modify the script

[image: Script Transformation Editor - Inputs and Outputs - ListPrice]

On the *`Script`* page of the *Script Transformation Editor*, perform the following actions.

- Click the ellipsis button against *ReadOnlyVariables* and select the variable *`User::ColumnDelimiter`*
- Click *`Edit Script...`*

[image: Script Transformation Editor - Script]

Paste the below C# in the Script Editor. The script performs the following tasks.

- Using the column delimiter value **`Ç`** defined in the variable *User::ColumnDelimiter*, the method *`FlatFileInput_ProcessInputRow`* splits the incoming value and assigns it to the two output columns defined in the Script Component transformation.

#### Script component code in C#

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
    }

    public override void FlatFileInput_ProcessInputRow(FlatFileInputBuffer Row)
    {
        const int COL_PRODUCT = 0;
        const int COL_PRICE = 1;

        char delimiter = Convert.ToChar(this.Variables.ColumnDelimiter);
        string[] lineData = Row.LineData.ToString().Split(delimiter);

        Row.ProductId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(lineData[COL_PRODUCT]) 
                            ? String.Empty 
                            : lineData[COL_PRODUCT];

        Row.ListPrice = String.IsNullOrEmpty(lineData[COL_PRICE]) 
                            ? 0 
                            : Convert.ToDecimal(lineData[COL_PRICE]);
    }
}
```

[image: Script Component Code - C#]

Drag and drop *`OLE DB Destination`* onto the *Data Flow* tab. Connect the green arrow from *Script Component* to *OLE DB Destination*. Double-click *OLE DB Destination* to open *`OLE DB Destination Editor`*.

On the *`Connection Manager`* page of the *OLE DB Destination Editor*, perform the following actions.

- Select *`Sora`* from *OLE DB Connection Manager*
- Select *`Table or view - fast load`* from *Data access mode*
- Select *`[dbo].[ProductListPrice]`* from *Name of the table or the view*
- Click *Mappings* page

[image: OLE DB Destination Editor - Connection Manager]

Click `Mappings` page on the *OLE DB Destination Editor* would automatically map the columns if the input and output column names are same. Click *`OK`*.

[image: OLE DB Destination Editor - Mappings]

*Data Flow* tab should look something like this after configuring all the components.

[image: Data Flow tab]

Execute the query `select * from dbo.ProductListPrice` in the *SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)* to find the number of rows in the table. It should be empty before executing the package.

[image: Rows in table before package execution]

Execute the package. You will notice that the package successfully processed **9** rows. The flat file contains **10** lines but the first row is header with column names.

[image: Package execution without delimiter]

Execute the query `select * from dbo.ProductListPrice` in the *SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)* to find the **9** rows successfully inserted into the table. The data should match with flat file data.

[image: Rows in table after package execution]

The above example illustrated how to manually split the data using *Script Component* because the *Flat File Connection Manager* encounters error when configured the column delimiter **`Ç`**

### Issue Simulation:

This example shows a separate *Flat File Connection Manager* configured with column delimiter **`Ç`**, which executes but encounters a warning and does not process any lines.

Right-click on the *`Connection Managers`* and click *`New Flat File Connection...`* to create a connection to read the flat file. On the *`General`* page of the *Flat File Connection Manager Editor*, perform the following actions:

- Set *Connection manager name* to *`ProductListPrice_Cedilla`*
- Set Description to *`Flat file connection manager with Cedilla column delimiter.`*
- I have the file in the path *`C:\Siva\StackOverflow\Files\6268205\ProductListPrice.txt`* Select the flat file path.
- Select **`{LF}`** from *Header Row Delimiter*
- Check *`Column names in the first data row`*
- Click *`Columns`* page

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor - With Cedilla - General]

On the *`Columns`* page of the *Flat File Connection Manager Editor*, perform the following actions:

- Set *Row delimiter* to *`{LF}`*
- The column delimiter field may be disabled. Click *`Reset Columns`*
- Set *Column delimiter* to *`Ç`*
- Click *`Advanced`* page

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor - With Cedilla - Columns]

On the *`Advanced`* page of the *Flat File Connection Manager Editor*, perform the following actions:

- Set the *Name* to *`ProductId`*
- Set the *ColumnDelimiter* to *`Ç`*
- Set the *DataType* to *`Unicode string [DT_WSTR]`*
- Set the *Length* to *`30`*
- Click column `ListPrice`

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor - With Cedilla - Advanced - ProductId]

On the *`Advanced`* page of the *Flat File Connection Manager Editor*, perform the following actions:

- Set the *Name* to *`ListPrice`*
- Set the *ColumnDelimiter* to *`{LF}`*
- Set the *DataType* to *`numeric [DT_NUMERIC]`*
- Set the *DataPrecision* to *`12`*
- Set the *DataScale* to *`2`*
- Click *`OK`*

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor - With Cedilla - Advanced - ListPrice]

Drag and drop a `Data Flow task` onto the *Control Flow* tab and name it as *`File to database - With Cedilla delimiter`*. Disable the first data flow task.

[image: Data Flow Task 2]

Configure the second data flow task with *`Flat File Source`* and *`OLE DB Destination`*

[image: Data Flow Tab - 2]

Double-click the Flat File Source to open *`Flat File Source Editor`*. On the *`Connection Manager`* page of the *Flat File Source Editor*, select the *Flat File Connection Manager* `ProductListPrice_Cedilla` and click *Columns* page to configure the columns. Click *`OK`*.

[image: Flat File Source Editor - Cedilla]

Execute the package. All the components will display green color to indicate that the process was success but no rows will be processed. You can see that there are no rows numbers indication between the *`Flat File Source`* and *`OLE DB Destination`*

[image: Package Execution - Cedilla]

Click the *`Progress`* tab and you will notice the following warning message.

```
[Read flat file [1]] Warning: The end of the data file was reached while 
reading header rows. Make sure the header row delimiter and the number of 
header rows to skip are correct.
```

[image: Progress Warning message]

Comment: This is an incredible answer. I cannot express my thanks enough. This should be a highlight example of stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for this, couldnt get any better.

Answer (score 1):

Answer above seems awfully complicated, just convert the line endings in the file

```
Dim FileContents As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("c:\Temp\UnixFile.csv")

Dim NewFileContents As String = FileContents.Replace(vbLf, vbCrLf)

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:\temp\WindowsFile.csv", NewFileContents, False, New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding)
```

Rehashed from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/801472cc-358d-4e60-a9ac-10573ef494af/how-to-convert-a-crlf-doswindows-to-lf-unix?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: Don't confuse a long post with complication. It might appear complicated, but it is incredibly well written and explains the method brilliantly. By contrast, your answer is far lower quality and isn't clear how it even answers the question in the first place. Keep in mind this is a question from over 5 years ago

Answer (score 0):

This issue also arises if you are trying to consume FlatFile generated on a different platform like Unix, Mac etc via SSIS on windows

In such a scenario all you need to do is convert the file format from say UNIX to DOS with unix2dos command

```
unix2dos file-to-convert
```