# SSIS: How can I handle a form feed delimiter in flat file source?

Tags: ssis, flat-file

I am currently trying to process a flat file in SSIS that uses a form feed character as the row delimiter. What would be the best way to handle this delimiter?

Comment: My approach was going to be to create a variable, FormFeed that is the FF character. I was then going to set expressions on `HeaderRowDelimiter` and `RowDelimiter` It's an approach I had used with "weird" delimiters but saving the package results in `An invalid character was found in text content.`  You could probably design the flat file CM with say, a comma so it saves and then assign that value at run-time to match the real format. Ugly though

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the answer provided to the following SO question. The example in the answer explains step-by-step how you can process a file that has Line Feed as the row delimiter and the example uses Ç (c-cedilla) as the column delimiter. You can change the column delimiter according to your requirements. This is one way, may not be the best way that you are looking for, of processing a file with Line Feed as row delimiter.

[Why doesn't SSIS recognize line feed {LF} row delimiter while importing UTF-8 flat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268205/utf-8-flat-file-import-to-sql-server-2008-not-recognizing-lf-row-delimiter/6270657)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I previously read this answer, hoping that it would work in my case, but unfortunately it did not work as I had hoped. My main problem is that the flat file already has the LF as the column delimiter and the row delimiter is the FF. So I end up with either a one column wide result set with N rows, or one row with N columns, neither of which work with your otherwise excellent solution.